# Wordpress : Add a translated string to a variable?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to save a translated string in a variable without displaying it.

I have actually this code :

```
<?php $str = _e('mystring', 'myplugin' ); ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__()` function that returns the value. `_e()` echo's the value to screen.

Use

```
<?php $str = __('mystring', 'myplugin' ); ?>
```